# Вывести значение функции за свои пределы JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, переменные

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вынести значение переменной `pos` за пределы функции, в которой он находиться?

Глобально объявлять нельзя.

Пробовал делать через return, и объявлять функцию, но не помогает:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function first() {
    $('.taglist:checked').each(function(i) {
      let pos = $(event.target).closest('body').find('.list-textbox-item .taglist').index($(event.target).closest('.list-textbox-item .taglist'));
      return pos;
    });
    //Вывести значение переменной 'pos' необходимо в текущую область.     
    $('.list-textbox-item textarea:eq(pos)').val(allVals).attr('rows', allVals.length);    
  }
});
```

<sub>HTML структуру загружать не стал, так как в этом нет необходимости.</sub>

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А откуда берётся `event.target`, присутствующий в `pos`? (не нашел в коде)

Comment: `$(event.target).closest('body')` - wtf?

Comment: @Arthur Видимо, расчет на глобальную переменную `event`, которой нет в Firefox-е.

Comment: @Igor, так вышло, что у заказчика нет общего контейнера, типа main, и он ему не нужен. В body сразу же начинается поочередная структура дивов. Вот я и начал обход (closest) с body.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, думаю есть смысл выложить HTML и описать конкретнее задачу механики. Может кто напишет лучший способ решения данной задачи.

Comment: `$('.taglist:checked').each(` ?! Для чего тут перебор? Элемент никак не участвует в написанном коде, а в pos несколько раз присваивается одно и то же значение... Не понятно в чем проблема просто сразу написать `let pos = $(event.target).closest...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [IIFE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiP-LiY3srqAhWii8MKHZR3DkgQFjAEegQIERAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FGlossary%2FIIFE&usg=AOvVaw1CP0sdxqWSRo3rxvRMR2HZ) чтобы ограничить scope переменной `let`:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let pos   
    function first() {
      $(".taglist:checked").each(function(i) {
        pos = $(event.target).closest("body").find(".list-textbox-item .taglist").index($(event.target).closest(".list-textbox-item.taglist"))
      })
    }
    // вывести значение переменной "pos" необходимо в текущую область
    $(".list-textbox-item textarea:eq(pos)").val(allVals).attr("rows", allVals.length)
  })
})(jQuery)
```

Или же воспользоваться [замыканием](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjNt4em3srqAhWKtIsKHcRzCS0QFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fru%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FClosures&usg=AOvVaw0jZB4O5urOVE18UZqvrjXp).